# PostgreSQL create count, count distinct columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery, distinct

fairly new to PostgreSQL and trying out a few count queries. I'm looking to count and count distinct all values in a table. Pretty straightforward -

```
CountD  Count
351     400
```

With a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
COUNT(id) AS count_id,
COUNT DISTINCT(id) AS count_d_id
FROM table
```

I see that I can create a single column this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table) AS count_d_id
```

But the title (count_d_id) doesn't come through properly and unsure how can I add an additional column. Guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count_d_id
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original query aliases the subquery rather than the column. You seem to want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_d_id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table) t
 -- column alias --^                           -- subquery alias --^
```

Comment: ok great thanks! That added in the column name properly - how can I include the additional count column?